# How do I know how many dies are contained in a certain package?

Tags: integrated-circuit, packages, semiconductors

For example, an IL485E that has a 16 SO(W) package -- how many dies are in the device?

Answer (score 1):

You really can't unless you break it apart and look, or the manufacturer tells you (and you believe them). Maybe an X-ray would help.

Why do you care?

Comment: I am curious because there are SiPs and even though by definition there are multiple dies in the package, I don't really know how many.

Comment: TO request clarification (like "why do you care?") it's better to use a comment than an answer.

Comment: @ThePhoton Okay, next time since s/he already answered.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is two.

[image]

Picture from http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/CMOS-Digital-Isolators-WP.pdf

Comment: Looks like a pretty good "guess".